# Semaphore for control downloadinf process

Tags: c#, download, synchronization, semaphore

I use Semaphore In this code

```
static Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1,1);
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                 Thread[] t = new Thread[full_list];
                 for(int i=0;i<full_list;i++)
                 {    
                     if (sorted_list[i].audio_node != null)
                         if (sorted_list[i].audio_node.Checked == true)
                         {
                             t[i] = new Thread(DownloadFile);
                             t[i].Start(sorted_list[i]);
                         }
                  }

           }

private  void DownloadFile(object a)
        {
            s.WaitOne();
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new DownloadFileDelegate(DownloadFile),new object[1] {a} );
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                download process....

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            s.Release();
        }
```

But it doesn't work, my prorgram freezes. I am trying solve this problem, but i don't know why it doesn't work with Semaphore. All components include downloading work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `DownloadFile` on a non-gui thread. In the method you acquire the semaphore, and then call `InvokeRequired`. It will return `true` as you're not on the gui thread, so you're invoke `DownloadFile on the gui thread. You then return without releasing the semaphore, so when`DownloadFile` runs on the gui thread the first thing it will try to do is acquire the semaphore, and because it can't it will block.

There's not much point in creating a thread in your code that is just going to schedule a call back on the gui thread. What you really need to do is download the file on the non-gui thread, and then when you've got it make a call back onto the gui thread to handle what you've downloaded.

Regarding the semaphore, you should wrap the code in a `try\finally` block to make sure it's always released, even if you've got a return in the middle of the code:

```
s.WaitOne();
try
{
  // Rest of method
}
finally
{
  s.Release();
}
```

Comment: Regarding the downloading, I want to show progress in Gui when i download.

Comment: @jenius - as you're downloading on one thread you can call a `BeginInvoke` a method on the gui thread to say how much has been downloaded, any update the gui accordingly.

Comment: And I do this, now semaphore doesn't freeze my program, but it still allows to download 2 or more files simultaneously. This is unacceptable for me.

Comment: @jenius - you don't need a semaphore. Just have a `bool` that is set when you start downloading, and set it to false when you've finished downloading. You can then check if you're already downloading when you try to do it again. Alternativly, disable the button that starts the download until the download is complete, and this way the user won't be able to start more than one download.

Comment: For it I need some function, which will wait when bool changes.  And it shouldn't hold CPU there is no any function.

Comment: @jenius it you're looking to queue up files to download one at a time then just maintain a queue of files to download, and then when you've downloaded one just check queue to see if there are more to download. Your download function can be the one that checks this queue.

Comment: Thank you. It was so helpful.